# "Delusions dispelled" What grammar construction is this? Is this an idiom?

Tags: ellipsis, past-participles, postpositive-adjectives

I don't understand the grammar of this: *"You will be dazed **by the shock of delusions dispelled**."* (by George Johnson)  I think it means, "He is dazed by the shock that naturally comes from your delusions being dispelled because of what stands right before him: reality." But I'm not sure about the grammar of "shock of delusions dispelled".

How does one derive what this means from English grammar?

Comment: Context please.

Comment: It's an uncommon sentence, but I think it's not too weird. One simple way to understand a sentence's structure (as opposed to parsing a sentence as a tree) is to ask yourself rhetoric questions. For example, "What is the sentence about?" "It's about 'You will be dazed.'" "'You will be dazed,' by what?" "By a shock." "What shock?" "It's the shock of delusions dispelled." At this point, you should be able to think of "delusions dispelled" as "something" (I hope *of* is not your problem), but what exactly is "delusions dispelled"? It's (approx.) the state after delusions were dispelled.

Comment: If you have a grammar book, check out "past participles" in your book.

Comment: I agree that more context would be helpful. (A name like "George Johnson" is not context.) Where did this come from? A work of fiction, a news article, or a poem?

Comment: I read it as something of a deliberate ["double-entendre"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_entendre). With *shock = amazement*, *"Having [some] delusions dispelled will be amazing, and will leave you dazed"*. But there's also *shock = a crowd (of persons); a heap, bunch, **bundle (of things)*** (from OED), giving the alternative reading *"Having **such a large number** of delusions dispelled will leave you dazed"*.

Comment: It's nothing more than "dispelled delusions", except with [Noun-adjective reversal](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/161298/noun-adjective-reversal-was-it-ever-in-use-in-plain-speech) - the answers linked should shed some more light on the subjects.

Comment: The context sounds like one of those pithy endorsements by one author of another author's book as typically found on the inside cover or the back of a book. My educated guess would be [George Johnson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Johnson_(writer), author and science writer for the New York Times. He's the kind of myth-busting, delusion-dispelling kind of guy that would say something like this. (Funnily enough, one might note the gerund-type postnominal adjectives I just used are related to this question.)

Comment: @SF, While I might agree that "delusions dispelled" could be thought of as "dispelled delusions" as a simplified equivalence to explain the meaning to the OP in this case, I don't think this issue is always so simple, and the link you provided was specifically addressing *postpositive adjectives-proper* rather than *postpositive adjectival past participles*. See [my answer below](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/26774/3796) for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at it this way: "You will be dazed by the shock of delusions that have been dispelled."

So, clearly you understand the sentence.  It looks like you didn't understand that "that have been" can be inferred by the context.  This sort of abbreviation is pretty common.  For example:

> The goals scored in the current World Cup are among the finest in its history.
>   The goals that have been scored in the current World Cup are among the finest in its history.

This is the same idea, and perhaps a more obvious example.

Comment: A normal case of [Whiz-Deletion](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/50971/15299), leaving a passive participle.

Answer (score 3):

**It's an adjective:** In "delusions dispelled" the participle is functioning as an adjective. This can cause confusion with language learners simply because there is a lot more emphasis and material on the role of the past participle as part of English verb conjugations.

**How to decide between verb and adjective form?** If a word answers "what action happened?" then it's acting as part of a verb (and this will typically be obvious as a verb conjugation). If a word answers the question "which?" or "what kind?" then it's acting as an adjective.

**But it still retains a verb-like quality!**  The adjectival participle describes "which" or "what kind?" by virtue of the state or action it has taken or been subjected-to.

**Participles as Verbs:** Let's first review some familiar verb conjugations. You can easily understand these as part of the action of the sentence.  "He **had dispelled** his delusion" and "He **dispelled** his delusion" both use 'dispelled' to simply describe the action (the verb of the sentence), forming the past perfect and past tense, respectively.

**Participles as Adjective:** In the sentence, "He was dismayed by his **dispelled delusion**", the word 'dispelled' describes *which delusion* and is therefore acting as an adjective. But even as an adjective, it describes it in a verb-like manner.

**Rhetorical Usage/Elliiptical Construction:** Placed after the noun (called postpostive position), participles often form an [elliptical construction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_%28linguistics%29) (omission of one or more words that are understood in context).  Rhetorically, this allows brevity, euphony (pleasing to the ear), and powerful punchy phrases.  This also allows an elliptical construction (dropping additional information) which creates a more passive and distant tone that can avoid naming responsibility.  Therefore, this form is often used in government and business documents to sound more authoritative and less connected to actual people or groups.  Statements made in the passive voice are weaker, but the missing words can make it more easily accepted (because there's less information to argue against) or hide the people responsible for making decisions.

**Examples of Elliptical Constructions.**

- Many of the **species involved** are listed internationally 
  as endangered. (The species involved *in the study*...)
- The **product used** was made by boiling a quantity of 
  hops with treacle** (The product used *by the company's process*...)
- Because of this the **skill required** is often very 
  challenging. (The *skill required by the employee to do the job right*...)
- The amount of **detail given** will have to be appropriate 
  to the type of system installed. (The *detail given by the supplier's instruction manual*...)
- Further **efforts made** are likely to fail for a number 
  of reasons. (Further *efforts made by any military action*...)
- The **issues raised** are more diverse and just as difficult. (The *issues raised by Senator XYZ*...)
- All of the **ideas suggested** were not feasible. (The *ideas suggested by the committee*...)

---

References:

<sup>1. [*A Guide to Parts of Speech - Adjectives*](http://www.grossmont.edu/karl.sherlock/English098/PartsOfSpeech/Adjectives.html)
Google Search ["postpositive+adjectives"+participles](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22postpositive+adjectives%22+participles).</sup>
<sup>2. Exceptions are idiomatic [deverbal adjectives](https://www.google.com/search?q=deverbal+adjectives)).</sup>  
<sup>3. *Postpositive Past Participles Used on Their Own* (Furuta, Yae, International Journal of Social Science and Humanity, Vol 2, No. 6, 2012).</sup>  
<sup>4. Bibliography for the quotes referenced by Faruta: **(1.)** R. Quirk, S. Greenbaum, G. Leech, and J. Svartvik, A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language, New York: Longman, 1985. **(2.)** M. Swan, Practical English Usage, 3rd ed., Oxford University Press, 2005. **(3)** K. Araki and M. Yasui, Sanseido’s New Dictionary of English Grammar, Tokyo: Sanseido, 1993.</sup>
<sup>5. Semantics of adjectival participles:  [`participles eventives resultatives statives`](https://www.google.com/search?q=participles+eventives+resultatives+statives).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

[*dispel*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/dispel) by definition

> to scatter and drive away; cause to vanish; disperse

So I suppose *delusions dispelled* refers to delusions that were made to go away. Probably that could mean a number of things. I suppose *reality* could be one of them.